# Python: Scraping a table for specific content

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am attempting to scrape a specific part of a specific table on a website.

```
URL = https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9775A
```

Within the website, there is an HTML table that I am trying to scrape from, which I am able to do, however, I am getting a lot of other items of the table i do not need. If you look at the URL, the table consists of multiple drop down lists, and i only need the "Current Releases" list.

Inspecting the element gives me this to work with [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcX3Q.png)

As you can see, there are a number of Table rows with the type "Current_Releases", but I can't figure out how to pull -just- those.

I am using Python 3.2 and BeautifulSoup, as well as requests and csv of course

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9775A"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"})
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
  rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])
with open('c:\source\output_file.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(headers)
  writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice and help as I am a novice when it comes to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `table.find_all('tr')` with `table.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 
'Current_Releases')` will find `<tr>` with attributes `releasetype` as `Current_Releases`.

Checkout [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) for more info.

Update: Adding complete code

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9775A"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"})
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 'Current_Releases'}):
    item = []
    for val in row.find_all('td'):
        item.append(val.text.encode('utf8').strip())
    rows.append(item)

with open('output_file.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(headers)
  writer.writerows(rows)
```

Gave me a CSV file with output

```
Version,Build Date,Posted Date,Notes,Size,Select
YA.16.03.0004,17-Apr-2017,24-Apr-2017,Release notes,13.5 MB,»
YA.16.02.0018,30-Mar-2017,06-Apr-2017,Release notes,12.7 MB,»
YA.16.01.0012,26-Jan-2017,01-Feb-2017,Release notes,12.5 MB,»
YA.15.18.0013,01-Sep-2016,22-Sep-2016,Release notes,11.9 MB,»
YA.15.16.0019m (Maintenance),27-Mar-2017,29-Mar-2017,Release notes,10.2 MB,»
```

Comment: @KevinJohnson updated my answer with the expected output and complete code.

Comment: Amazing. <3 Thank you so much. It looks like you included an xml parser and changed a few things up. This is exactly what I needed

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept and upvote the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Already did sir. The upvote doesn't count because I'm not very reputable yet.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!